# Periodic Interest Calculation In Power Query/Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, finance

I need to calculate accumulated interest on an account. So far I have tried using the `List.Accumulate()` and `List.Generate()` functions to loop through the quarterly balance, but I am still not getting the right results. I tried the following expression in Power Query, but no luck.

```
List.Accumulate(
    List.Range(#"Added Index"[interest],0,[Index]),
    0,
    (Opening,Current)=>Opening+Current
)
```

In DAX, I get a circular reference error, trying to perform the same loop:

```
BalanceBOQ = [Contribution] 
    + [Interest Earned(EOQ)] 
    - [FixedExpBOQ-Withdrawals(EOQ)] 
    - [Variable Expenses(EOQ)]

Interest Earned(EOQ) = ( ( [BalanceBOQ ]+ [Contribution] ) 
    - [FixedExpBOQ] ) ) * [Rate]
```

How can I loop through the quarterly balance to calculate periodic interest?

[image: Image Description]

Answer (score 0):

The key is actually not to view interest as cumulative, but as the future value of each cash flow. Pseudo-code:

```
 Ending Balance =
 Round( Calculate(
     SUMX( 
         activity_list,
         FV( daily_rate, NOW() - date, 0, value )
     ),
     Datesbetween( 'Calendar'[date], Blank(), Lastdate( 'Calendar'[date] ) )
 ), 2)

Period Interest = [Ending Balance] 
   - Calculate( [Ending Balance], dateadd( firstdate( 'Calendar'[date] ), -1, day ) ) 
   - Sum( value )
```

In your case `value` would be the total change in value each quarter, and you would probably substitute the daily rate for a quarterly rate and convert the number of days argument to number of quarters. These are written as measures, but could be converted to calculated columns as well.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..I have tried to read your code but it is advanced for me..is it possible if I can get sample pbix from it